# Profile page overlap

Tags: bug, design, activity

Profile page is appearing jumbled up in both new and old design:

[image: Activity in old theme and design]

[image: Activity in new theme and design]

Comment: I have similar (worse?) issues on my profile page in MSE. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C2ui.png)

Comment: Which browser and operating system are you using here? Could be relevant for reproducing a platform-specific bug.

Comment: @doppelgreener chromium web browser ubuntu. Can't replicate same on chrome and Firefox.